# fullcalendar io 6.1.8 add event filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I need to add event filtering to my calendar

I added a special select for this and a function for this select that should update the calendar

But I had a problem that this function only works once. Let's say I launch the calendar, select a filter, everything is displayed as it should. But when I try to immediately change the filter to another one, all the events disappear altogether, what’s the problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.8/index.global.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: [
          {
            title: 'Event 1',
            start: '2024-01-01',
            dataFilter: 'filter1'
          },
          {
            title: 'Event 2',
            start: '2024-01-02',
            dataFilter: 'filter2'
          },
        ],
        eventClick: function(info) {
          alert('Event: ' + info.event.title);
        },
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
      });

      calendar.render();

      var filterSelect = document.getElementById('filterSelect');

      filterSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
        var selectedFilter = filterSelect.value;

        var filteredEvents = calendar.getEvents().filter(function(event) {
          return selectedFilter === 'all' || event.extendedProps.dataFilter === selectedFilter;
        });

        calendar.setOption('events', filteredEvents);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <label for="filterSelect">Select event:</label>
  <select id="filterSelect">
    <option value="all">All events</option>
    <option value="filter1">Event 1</option>
    <option value="filter2">Event 2</option>
  </select>

  <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tiny bit of debugging shows that `filteredEvents` contains one item after you filter by "Event 1" first, and then *none* any more, when you filter by "Event 2" next. And that in turn is due to the fact, that `calendar.getEvents()` only returns the *already* filtered set of events.

Keep your events in a separate variable outside of the FullCalendar initialization, so that you can use that *original* data set again when you filter:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.8/index.global.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let events = [
          {
            title: 'Event 1',
            start: '2024-01-01',
            dataFilter: 'filter1'
          },
          {
            title: 'Event 2',
            start: '2024-01-02',
            dataFilter: 'filter2'
          },
        ];
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: events,
        eventClick: function(info) {
          alert('Event: ' + info.event.title);
        },
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
      });

      calendar.render();

      var filterSelect = document.getElementById('filterSelect');

      filterSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
        var selectedFilter = filterSelect.value;

        var filteredEvents = events.filter(function(event) {
          return selectedFilter === 'all' || event.dataFilter === selectedFilter;
        });

        calendar.setOption('events', filteredEvents);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <label for="filterSelect">Select event:</label>
  <select id="filterSelect">
    <option value="all">All events</option>
    <option value="filter1">Event 1</option>
    <option value="filter2">Event 2</option>
  </select>

  <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```